# Is it possible to change shape of Android Toolbar from the default rectangle in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

Problem : Trying to achieve Toolbar with arched bottom. The content when scrolling should go through this arc space.

- Only thing I could think of (as well as tried) is to set the background of toolbar with a drawable which has arch. Lookwise it solves things. But then when the content is scrolled up, the white space in the arch remain, since Toolbar maintains it's rectangle shape.
- I'm also trying to avoid using custom shapes instead of Toolbar because this toolbar is part of a Collapsibletoolbarlayout and Appbarlayout controlled by Coordinator layout.

Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: @commonsware Have you come across this scenario before ? Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: can you guys help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648733/android-nestedscrollview-under-appbar-with-custom-shape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <!--Other collapsing toolbar components here-->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!--Your content here-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/curve"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `FrameLayout` anchored to the bottom of the `AppBarLayout` acts as the container for the arch. I created a vector drawable that I used as the background for the `FrameLayout`

**curve.xml**

```
<vector android:width="100dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportHeight="50"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <path
        android:pathData="M0,0L400,0L400,50Q200,-50,0,50L0,0"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</vector>
```

Change the `android:height` property of the drawable to control how high you want the arch to go

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I think you're very close to the solution. I ran your code. The text goes into the arc. But as I mentioned in the second part of my question,  I wanted to keep the Collapsibletoolbarlayout action to be intact. This actually breaks it. 
Could you please run your code and verify this ?

Comment: @RmK I have included the output. It works well enough for me.

Comment: Thanks Ajil. And the scrolling content is going through the arc ? Could you please share the output of that too ?

Comment: This is the response I'm getting. Basically, the text is going inside and over the arch. (Hence my initial thought of modifying the toolbar itself). https://imgur.com/a/4XRGI

Comment: Sure you have not missed `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`? If possible post the code you are using @RmK

Comment: You can find my code here - https://pastebin.com/21YMEsbR and here https://pastebin.com/kr2ZZYt9

Can you also please post a screenshot of the content going through the arc ?

Comment: @RmK Edited the output. I'll go through your code and get back

Comment: Hi, the edited output still doesn't have the text going through the arc space. Please verify.

Comment: @RmK What do you mean the text is not going through the arc space?

Comment: My bad. I guess the screen refresh never worked. Marked your answer as correct

Comment: Hello, could you all a similar shape such as the printer flow chart icon shape but inverted. Thanks!

Comment: can you guys help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648733/android-nestedscrollview-under-appbar-with-custom-shape